# How do you validate Symfony BirthdayType fields?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

I'm trying to validate a BirthdayType field. The form field is like this:

```
->add('birthday', BirthdayType::class, [
    'placeholder' => [
        'year' => 'select-year',
        'month' => 'select-month',
        'day' => 'select-day',
    ]
])
```

And the field validation is defined like this:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Date(
 *      message = "Field should be a date"
 * )
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *      groups = {"Signup"},
 *      message = "Field must not be blank"
 * )
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="birthday")
 */
 private $birthday;
```

On form submit, this is what's posted to the controller:

```
[form] => Array
    (
        [birthday] => Array
            (
                [year] => 
                [month] => 
                [day] => 
            )
    ...
    )
```

When the validation runs, all other form fields are validated properly except for this one.
Am I missing something obvious that's preventing this field from being validated as a Date/Birthday?

I've tried adding these to the form field but they appear to have had no effect:

```
'error_bubbling' => true//false,
'compound' => false//true
```

Answer (score 1):

The BirthdayType return a Datetime [Symfony Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html)

In your @ORM\Column annotation try to set type="date".